# If A is normal, then the nullspace of A is the nullspace of A*

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a normal matrix. Prove that $x$ is in the nullspace of $A$ if and only if $x$ is in the nullspace of $A^{*}$.

This isn't a homework problem. It was on a test I took recently, and I'd like to know if I was on the right track in solving it.

Comment: $\ker A = \ker A^* A$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose that $A \in \mathbb {C}^{n \times n}$. Then
$$\left\Vert Ax \right\Vert^2 =  \left\langle Ax , Ax \right\rangle = \left\langle A^* Ax , x \right\rangle  = \left\langle AA^* x , x \right\rangle = \left\langle A^*x , A^*x \right\rangle = \left\Vert A^*x \right\Vert^2 .$$
Hence, 
$$Ax =0 \Leftrightarrow \left\Vert Ax \right\Vert = 0 \Leftrightarrow \left\Vert A^*x \right\Vert = 0 \Leftrightarrow A^*x = 0 $$

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ker}{ker} \DeclareMathOperator{\dim}{dim}$We have in fact the more general statement $\ker(A) = \ker(A^*A)$.

The direction $\subseteq$ is clear. We know that the dimension of the nullspace of a matrix is the number of the zero eigenvalues it has, if $A = U D U^*$, then we see that $A^*A = U D^2 U^*$, i.e. all non-zero eigenvalues of $A^*A$ correspond to the non-zero eigenvalues of $A$, in particular we must have

$$\dim \ker A = \dim \ker(A^*A)$$

which means, the inclusion $\ker(A) \to \ker(A^*A)$ must be a bijection, i.e. $\ker(A) = \ker(A^*A)$.

The desired result follows from $A^*A = AA^*$, i.e. $\ker A = \ker(A^*A) = \ker(AA^*) = \ker A^*$.

Comment: I didn't know that; thanks for the added information

Comment: don't you need $ker(A^TA) = ker(AA^T)$  to show $A = UDV^T?$

Comment: Read the question statement. $A$ is normal, i.e. $A^*A = AA^*$.

Comment: how do you know $A = UDU*$ if $A$ is normal?

Comment: I assume it is the spectral decomposition of $A$. The spectral theorem also holds for normal matrices.